# Create React project from another React project(template)

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

i use command line to create a new project for react :

```
npx create-react-app templatereact
```

... oky it's create for me a 'templatereact' project and downloaded  130 mb file
now again when i want to create a new project with 'create-react-app' i should to download 130 mb again and again and if i don't have internet i cant't create new project with 'create-react-app'
for this reason i want to create a new project from  'templatereact' for that I copied the entire folder 'templatereact' to new place and rename it to 'myreact' folder and in package.json i change name from "name": "templatereact", to "name": "myreact",. now when i run 'npm start' i give erros :

```
> myreact@0.1.0 start C:\tutorial\React&Redux\myreact
> react-scripts start

'\myreact\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:800
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\tutorial\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js'
←[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:10)←[39m
←[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m,
  requireStack: []
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! myreact@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the myreact@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-10T05_11_53_505Z-debug.log
```

now I don't know what other configurations I need to make on the new project 'myreact'.

Please tell me what configuration I need to do ??

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the package.json file which has a bunch of startup scripts / shortcuts defined.
Lookout for something like this:

```
"scripts": {
"start": "npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js",
"build": "npm run build-css && react-scripts build",
"watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./src -- 
 include-path ./node_modules src/ -o src/ --watch --recursive",
 "build-css": "node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./src --include-path 
 ./node_modules src/ -o src/",
 "start-js": "react-scripts start"
},
```

And check whether the absolute path is same as the path of your new project. From the error it seems like it is not able to fine the react-scripts.js file.